# how to find same id and group and count the same id on different days

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

currently i have a database structure like this :-
[image]

what i want to create (in laravel eloquent) is first get user_id and date_access. then based on the dates for example on the 2018-03-07 the are 3 rows, so user_id 1 have 2 times so = 2018-03-07 => 2
this is because it should group same user_id together to make it 1 and another user_id plus together..

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
$collections = DB::table('my_table')
                 ->select(DB::raw('count(user_id) as users'))
                 ->groupBy('date_access')
                 ->get();
```